# HTML + PHP - how to send uploaded file to server

Tags: php, html

I want to use a PHP as a proxy to upload files to server. How can i send the uploaded files to a server together with Basic Authorization header?

Comment: Are you thinking about Basic **Authentication** instead of Authorization

Comment: Nope. The header name is Authorization

Comment: Have you looked into using Nginx(or another webserver) instead of PHP for this purpose? You will experience much better performance that way.

Comment: Oh and it will also be easier to setup :)

Answer (score 0):

Is PECL ssh2 an option?  If it is, then you won't need the authentication header as you can do authentication through ssh.  If not, then you can use cURL to set the header and send the information to a script on another server that is designed to receive the upload (and under the http authentication requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) headers:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/path/"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 80);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array('Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='));
```

cURL provides other options like `CURLOPT_FILE` that can help your specific case.